# How can an x86 application detect that it's running in AMD64 compatibility mode?

Tags: x86, x86-64, detection

In general, without using OS-specific methods, how can an x86 application detect that it's running in AMD64 compatibility mode instead of legacy mode?

I know I can get `cr0` in user space by just doing `smsw eax` or similar non-privileged instruction (useful to check whether e.g. paging/cache/... is enabled), but after reading Intel's System Programming Guide section 9.8.5 *Initializing IA-32e Mode*, I learned that this is hardly useful, because IA-32e mode is enabled via `IA32_EFER` MSR, which is inaccessible to ring 3 code. So is there still any way to reliably discriminate between legacy and compatibility modes?

Comment: http://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64#How_do_I_detect_if_the_CPU_is_64_bits_.3F points out that `CPUID` will tell you if the cpu supports long mode, but doesn't shed any light on your question.  I think the fact that no detection method is mentioned on that page is a small piece of evidence that there isn't one for user-space.

Answer (score 0):

This [Superuser post](https://superuser.com/questions/383711/whats-the-difference-between-intel-64-and-amd64/383943#383943) points out that on Intel implementations, SYSCALL is supported in legacy mode, but not compatibility mode.  This is technically OS specific, but you're not *asking the OS* for the answer, like just calling `uname(2)` and looking at `buf->machine`.  If you know a "normal" system call, like gettimeofday or getpid, you can try it with this.

Intel's manual says SYSCALL will:  `#UD   If IA32_EFER.SCE = 0.`

Although this only works if you OS supports using SYSCALL from 32bit code in the first place.  32bit code normally has to use `int 80h`.  64bit code normally does use SYSCALL, though.

**Apparently AMD64 CPUs don't work this way, only Intel EMT64**, according to wikipedia (the source for that superuser post).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Recent_implementations doesn't mention anything else useful.

Comment: Yeah, this is Intel 64 specific. AMD64 CPUs support `syscall` in all three modes: legacy, compatibility and long, this can be read in their docs.